# List error when counting tokenised frequency

Tags: python, counter

I am getting errors after tokenising a column of dataframe in Python.

```
ue_df_c['category'] = ue_df_c['category'].astype(str)

# apply the `word_tokenize()` function
tokens = ue_df_c['category'].apply(word_tokenize)
```

```
Counter(tokens)
```

Output:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

```
print(tokens)
0                    [Burgers, ,, American, ,, Sandwiches]
1        [Coffee, and, Tea, ,, Breakfast, and, Brunch, ...
2        [American, ,, Cheesesteak, ,, Sandwiches, ,, A...
3                                                  [Pizza]
4        [Breakfast, and, Brunch, ,, Burgers, ,, Sandwi...
                               ...                        
45222    [Mexican, ,, Latin, American, ,, New, Mexican,...
45223      [Mexican, ,, Latin, American, ,, Family, Meals]
45224    [Mediterranean, ,, Greek, ,, Family, Meals, ,,...
45225                         [Thai, ,, Asian, ,, Noodles]
45226    [Breakfast, and, Brunch, ,, American, ,, Sandw...
Name: category, Length: 45227, dtype: object
```

How do I fix this so that I can get the frequency count for unique values and visualise?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`word_tokenize` produces a list of strings.  You're asking `Counter` to count the lists, not the words in the lists.  You need to join all the lists together.  You should be able to do

```
Counter(sum(tokens, []))
```